# how to use dotplot after clmm

Tags: r, lattice, multi-level, ordinal

I have tried to plot random effects after `clmm`, but I got error message: "Error in sort.list(y):'x' must be atomic for `sort.list' Have you called 'sort' an a list?" The following codes are representative of my actual codes.

```
library(ordinal)
library(lattice)

###I am using the wine data in the ordinal package
d<-data.frame(wine)
result<-clmm(rating~1+temp+contact+(1+temp|judge), data=d)
###In my actual codes, I put "as.ordered(rating)" instead of "rating".
```

Then, I am trying to plot random effects of temp and judge:

```
dotplot(ranef(result, condVar=TRUE))
```

Then, the error message appears: "Error in sort.list(y):'x' must be atomic for `sort.list' Have you called 'sort' on a list?"

My best guess is that rating is implemented as ordered under `clmm`, which seems for me to make sense given the error message. Yet, the guess is highly speculative, and I have no idea how to handle this situation. **Specifically, what I would like to plot is the random effects of temp and judge (intercept) with their CIs.** Please refer to the following plot that I generated using the codes below

```
result2<-lmer(as.numeric(rating)~1+temp+contact+(1+temp|judge), data=d)
dotplot(ranef(result2, condVar=TRUE))
```

[image: Plot from lmer]

If you could give any comment or suggestion on how to circumvent the seemingly-conflicting situation in which using `clmm` prevents me from using `dotplot` using the code above, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: What fo you want to show in your dotplot? ranef(result) returns a list of one element, which is a dataframe with two continuous variables, but no categorical variable.  I don't understand how you can show this in a dotplot (unless you mean scatterplot).  Or perhaps you want to show a dotplot of the coeeficients instead?. Please update the questio to indicate exactly what you wanrt in your plot

Comment: I think OP wants the equivalent of `lme4:::dotplot.ranef.mer`

Comment: Thanks dww and Ben, I will shortly refine my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started out trying to hack the guts of `lme4:::dotplot.ranef.mer`, but it turned out to be easier to do this with `reshape2::melt` and `ggplot2`.  Sorry if you have a really strong preference for `lattice` ...

Note by the way that, technically, these aren't "confidence intervals" (since the predicted conditional modes are not "estimates" in the technical, frequentist sense) ...

Rearrange point estimates and SEs of conditional modes into a useful shape:

```
library(reshape2)
melt.ranef.clmm <- function(re,cv) {
  reList <- lapply(re,
        function(x) {
           x$id <- reorder(factor(rownames(x)),x[,1])
           return(melt(x,id.var="id"))
        })
  cvList <- lapply(cv,melt,id.var=NULL,value.name="se")
  mm <- Map(cbind,reList,cvList)
  return(mm)
}
```

Apply this to a model (`m1` is a fitted model):

```
ss <- melt.ranef.clmm(ranef(m1),condVar(m1))
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(ss[[1]],aes(value,id))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=value-1.96*se,xmax=value+1.96*se),
                 height=0)+
  ggtitle(names(ss)[1])+
  geom_point(colour="blue")+
  facet_wrap(~variable,scale="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: oh thank you so much!!! I do not have strong preference for lattice at all! But, I poorly have systematic understanding of R, I just wanted to use a ready-made package I will try and get back soon.  Once again, I appreciate that you spent valuable time to work on this.

Comment: It works beautifully!! Thanks!! It took while because I got error when I put your codes without understanding what "m1" in your code meant.  After adjusting m1, everything works perfectly!!! I really appreciate your effort.  But, unfortunately, I would like to put the level IDs on the y axis. Although I know it would be pretty much demanding, I will also appreciate it if you could give me at least how to approach to putting level IDs.  Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: fixed.  It would be better (for me) to put the reshaping stuff into the `broom` package ...

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It works really beautifully!!!! Thank you thank you, I do not know how to express my feeling. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

`dotplot` does not know what to do with the result from `ranef(clmm(...))` as it has no associated method for this result.

The 'simple' answer is that you can set the class of the result (to the same class as provided by `ranef(lm34::lmer(...))`) to circumvent this:

```
r1 <- ranef(result, condVar=TRUE)
class(r1)="ranef.mer"
dotplot(r1)
```

This will get you a dotplot, but without the conditional standard error bars.

[image]

To also have the conditional error bars plotted need a little more effort. The problem is that `lme4::dotplot.ranef.mer` looks to find the errors in an attribute named `postVar`, whereas clmm provides them in a differently formatted attribute called `condVar`.  Fortunately, it is relatively simple to edit `dotplot.ranef.mer` to deal also with clmm objects.  we can do this by adding one line to the function:

```
if (!is.null(cv <- attr(xt, "condVar")))  se <- as.vector(unlist(cv))
```

Then we can get the plot using

```
result<-clmm(rating~1+temp+contact+(1+temp|judge), data=d)
r1 <- ranef(result, condVar=TRUE)
dp(r1, scales = list(x = list(relation = 'free')))
```

[image]

Here's the whole of the function to draw this plot. This is a verbatim copy of `dotplot.ranef.mer` with the one added line as mentioned above

```
dp <- function (x, data, main = TRUE, ...) 
{
  prepanel.ci <- function(x, y, se, subscripts, ...) {
    if (is.null(se)) 
      return(list())
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    hw <- 1.96 * as.numeric(se[subscripts])
    list(xlim = range(x - hw, x + hw, finite = TRUE))
  }
  panel.ci <- function(x, y, se, subscripts, pch = 16, horizontal = TRUE, 
                       col = dot.symbol$col, lty = dot.line$lty, lwd = dot.line$lwd, 
                       col.line = dot.line$col, levels.fos = unique(y), groups = NULL, 
                       ...) {
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    y <- as.numeric(y)
    dot.line <- trellis.par.get("dot.line")
    dot.symbol <- trellis.par.get("dot.symbol")
    sup.symbol <- trellis.par.get("superpose.symbol")
    panel.abline(h = levels.fos, col = col.line, lty = lty, 
                 lwd = lwd)
    panel.abline(v = 0, col = col.line, lty = lty, lwd = lwd)
    if (!is.null(se)) {
      se <- as.numeric(se[subscripts])
      panel.segments(x - 1.96 * se, y, x + 1.96 * se, y, 
                     col = "black")
    }
    panel.xyplot(x, y, pch = pch, ...)
  }
  f <- function(nx, ...) {
    xt <- x[[nx]]
    ss <- stack(xt)
    mtit <- if (main) 
      nx
    ss$ind <- factor(as.character(ss$ind), levels = colnames(xt))
    ss$.nn <- rep.int(reorder(factor(rownames(xt)), xt[[1]], 
                              FUN = mean, sort = sort), ncol(xt))
    se <- NULL
    if (!is.null(pv <- attr(xt, "postVar"))) 
      se <- unlist(lapply(1:(dim(pv)[1]), function(i) sqrt(pv[i, i, ])))
#############################################################
# Next line is the inseerted line to deal with clmm objects
#############################################################
    if (!is.null(cv <- attr(xt, "condVar"))) se <- as.vector(unlist(cv))
    dotplot(.nn ~ values | ind, ss, se = se, prepanel = prepanel.ci, 
            panel = panel.ci, xlab = NULL, main = mtit, ...)
  }
  setNames(lapply(names(x), f, ...), names(x))
}
```

Comment: this is nice, but integrating the conditional standard standard deviations will be harder ...

Comment: Thank you so much. this website is really incredible!! Thank you so much again. I will try and get back to let you know the result!

Comment: dww, it works very well. Thank you so much. since I need to present my current work to academic audiences, I would like to have CIs. Although I am aware that it is demanding to ask you to give some ideas on how to put CIs there, I will really appreciate if you do so. This is because I lack systematic understanding on R.  Anyway, I appreciate your work on this post.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes the error bars need a little extra effort.  Editted answer to include these also

Comment: @dww, thank you so much for your extra work to help me. As far as I know there is no practically useful instruction regarding using dotplot after clmm. So, I believe that your devoted work would help other R beginners like me.